# Php_flag engine не работает и php скрипт всё равно выполняется

Tags: .htaccess

Пишу в .htaccess php_flag engine 0 , но php скрипт всё равно выполняется. Уже голову сломал, всё перепробовал и php_flag engine off в том числе.

php как модуль апача, оверрайды включены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно ) только что проверил

```
php_flag engine 0
AddType "text/html" .php
```

Всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: А у меня это не работает, в чём может быть причина?